# Android Spinner Set dropdown text direction to RTL

Tags: android-studio, android-spinner, right-to-left

How to set spinner dropdown text direction to `rtl`?
I know for regular texts we can use `android:textDirection="rtl"` but it does not work for spinner dropdown text. Should I implement it in popup theme? How?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This will fix the issue.. enjoy

```
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This -

**Add below code in Activity**

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
R.array.planets_array,
//        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    R.layout.textview);
//    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.textview);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

**textview.xml**

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" />
```

**Change Gravity as per your requirement**... Hope this will help...

Answer (score 3):

First of all make sure that you enabled rtl support in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    ...>
```

after that use this in your `Spinner` definition :

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textDirection="rtl"
```