# Spinner direction not changed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner, right-to-left

[image: my ui in api 18 & 17]

[image: my ui in api 27]

Hi everybody

I have problem in setting spinners direction to RTl. 
In fact, my code dont work in api 17 & 18 in which layoutDirecton is supported ,
but it works perfectly in api 27 .

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layoutDirection="rtl" />
```

I searched the internet and found the usin of **ViewCompat** class as a solution that did not work.

I would be thankful if you guide me

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you enabled rtl support in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
...
android:supportsRtl="true"
...>
```

after that use this in your Spinner definition :

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58783793/1324) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that sorry !